# Is there any version of the Banach-Tarski paradox in ZF?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, amenability, banach-tarski

The Banach-Tarski paradox states that for a solid ball in 3‑dimensional space, there exists a decomposition into a finite number of disjoint subsets, which can then be put back together in a different way to yield two identical copies of the original one.

Obviously it is based on AC. I was wondering if anyone here knew if analysis under the axioms of ZF has been developed to invent a version of Banach-Tarski which is independent of AC.
What does the Banach-Tarski paradox look like without AC? Are there any versions of it? (For an example, one of the theorems that has been proven without AC is the Heine-Borel theorem.)

Comment: Depends on what you mean exactly. There are models of ZF in which every set of real numbers is measurable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model), which would prevent a lot of the paradoxes you might have in mind. This question is probably too basic for MO, though.

Comment: To add on to what @Sam wrote; many theorems in analysis either don't use choice, or their specific uses in classical analysis don't use choice (e.g. Baire Category Theorem is equivalent to Dependent Choice; but for separable spaces it is provable in ZF). Asking about development of the whole of analysis in ZF or ZF+DC is tantamount to going through Rudin (or some other book on analysis) and checking each theorem to see what you can or cannot do wit or without choice. Some places do that, to some extent (e.g. Schechter's book), but generally it's too broad of a question for a Q&A website.

Comment: "which is independent of AC": I guess you mean "which is a theorem of ZF". The formulation that P is independent of AC might (?) mean that both ZFC+P and ZFC+(not P) are consistent.

Comment: In light of the very nice answer of Paul, I retract my insinuation that this question might be too basic. But I will leave the link to the Solovay model, which is still certainly relevant for some considerations...

Comment: Given that the BT result deals with objects no bigger than $2^\mathfrak{c}$, certainly AC could be removed in favour of only needing it for very small sets at most. The question is what kind of weak choice principle is needed to establish the required results about how the free subgroup on two generators of SO(3) leads to the required decomposition. Incidentally, there is a thorough elementary discussion in this project report https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05714

Comment: The fact that there is no finitely-additive SO(3)-invariant measure on S2 with the discrete σ-algebra has been proven in ZF + Hahn-Banach by Foreman and Wehrung: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00004713
Their argument transports the lack of invariant measure from F2 to S2. It can then be used to transport F2's explicit paradoxical decomposition across: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm13813.pdf

Comment: A somewhat related twitter [thread](https://twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1428471658088738818)

Answer (score 57):

According to Dougherty and Foreman's 1992 PNAS paper, *Banach-Tarski paradox using pieces with the property of Baire* (doi:[10.1073/pnas.89.22.10726](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.89.22.10726)), the following result can be shown without AC: the unit ball has a finite collection of disjoint *open* subsets that transforms by rigid motions to another collection of disjoint open sets such that the *closure* of the union is two unit balls.

Comment: The "constructive" adjective most often includes not using the law of excluded middle. So "classically constructive" would be a more precise adjective in this case. (Uses of "constructive" are generally relative to the author and authors with more a restrictive notion of "constructive" tend to use it more often, so this is a touchy subject. On MO, and also in more general settings,a search often leads to "most often used in this context", so you can see this is sometimes problematic regardless of what you or anyone else thinks is most appropriate.) [FWIW: I am not a constructivist.]

Comment: The given citation is to the PNAS paper, and a fuller description is given (by the same authors) in: https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1994-07-01/S0894-0347-1994-1227475-8/home.html *one cannot explain away their paradoxical nature by
blaming it on [AC]. Instead, one can note that the open sets resulting from
our construction have boundaries of positive measure. When the open sets are
packed into a small space, these boundaries overlap greatly; when the open sets
are rearranged within a larger set, the boundary overlap is less extreme, so the
total measure of the closures is greater.*

Comment: In [this paper by Feferman](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1005223128130), the following is stated: "Not only does the proof not make use of AC, it is completely constructive in the data."  However, as noted by @FrançoisG.Dorais, the authors Dougherty and Foreman seem to use "constructive" to mean just avoidance of AC, so perhaps Feferman was mistaken?  This needs to be investigated.

Comment: I have removed my constructivity claim.

Comment: Reading again, I think Feferman was right and it really is constructive, but a more careful eye is needed than mine.  Some versions of constructivism have multiple not-provably-isomorphic versions of $\mathbb{R}$, so the question may be subtle.

Comment: At the end of Section 3 in the longer paper, they note one needs to: fix an enumeration of the given countable group of homeomorphisms, fix an enumeration of a countable dense subset of the given separable metric space X (thereby giving a countable base for its topology, via rational radii), and give a constructive proof of the Baire category theorem.

Comment: This fact is quite amazing to me! Thanks for bringing it into this forum! :)

Comment: The paper explicitly clarifies constructive to mean without the use of AC. Not saying the theorem is not actually possible in intuitionistic logic, though, just that the paper doesn't seem to be claiming it works in that setting.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if this means AC is hidden in the definition of closure. I mean, closure operator can be split to epimorphism and section [1] which form a Galois connection (the closure operator can be recovered by composition). But the section itself is normally proven to exist by the AC which states that every epi has section. So assuming closure exists assumes AC? Or we must assume AC to split the closure to epi and section?
[1] Lawvere, Rosebrugh:Sets for Mathematics

Comment: @EsaPulkkinen What is wrong with the elementary definition of the closure of a set as the intersection of all closed sets containing it?

Comment: @Timothy Chow When you have an open set and construct its closure, where do the additional limit points come from? I mean typically they represent "points at infinity" of sequences of elements taken from the open sets. When you consider cl S as intersection of all closed sets containing S, can the "all closed sets" (including their limit points) be assumed to exist without invoking AC?

Comment: @Esa yes, they exist by the definition of a topology (the open sets are the data of a topology, the closed sets are their complements). No AC is needed. The new points in the closure are already elements of the given space. It seems you may be thinking of a completion, which is not what is happening here.

Comment: @David Roberts Yes, thank you.